# Dalekjs Nesting Tests

Tags: javascript, dalekjs

I'm trying to get nested tests to work so I can use a masterfile to run different sets of tests.  I followed the example but I get errors each time.

I have this first file: calculator.js

```
 module.exports = {
'calc': function(test) {
    test
        .open('http://www.privatestudentloans.com/learn/repayment/loan-payment-calculator/')
        .waitForElement('article')
        .assert.exists('#psl-calc', 'Calculator has loaded')
}
```

}

On its own the test runs fine.  But then I try to call it from another test file, master.js:

```
var calculator = require('./calculator');
module.exports = {
'tests': function(test) {
    calculator.calc(test);
    .done();
}
```

}

And when trying this I keep getting the error:

> > WARNING:
> >     SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
> >     Failure loading suite "master.js". Skipping!SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

So which . is it mad about?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like the problem was trying to run .done() after the ; at the end of the first test. So master.js should instead be:

```
var calculator = require('./calculator');
module.exports = {
'tests': function(test) {
calculator.calc(test)
.done(); 
}
}
```

Or if you're chaining multiple included files together:

```
var calculator = require('./calculator');
var psl = require('./psl');
module.exports = {
'tests': function(test) {
    log.message('Starting Calc Test 1')
    .calculator.calc(test)
    .log.message('Starting Test 2')
    .psl.calculator(test)
    .done();
}
}
```